# Can you force a GPO update from a different user

Tags: active-directory, runas, gpo

I am getting a "fail to update user" when executing a "gpupdate /force". The computer updates fine. I think the issue has to do with the computer is logged on as userX. I am running a cmd window with "runas /user:userY" I will answer the inevitable question "why" at the end of the post. The meat of the question, is this (runas /user:userY can failed is expected) correct? If so can I get around it.

The computer has to autolog on with a domain user that has administrative privileges, users are prevented from access to any from of disk "explorer" including IE. Long story, just trust me. I been able to hand all needed cloud applications by using .net webbrowser. Now we want to go with a 3rd party cloud application. For the .net browser to work, I would have to expand .net browser to basically be another IE and I don't want to reinvent the wheel. For various reasons, I don't want to lock down IE for the always logged on userX admin, so we had this idea of creating a userY and filtering a "RestrictIE" GPO on it. So there would be a script (.bat) that would be from the .net launched with a runas command. The problem appears that since the userY is never logged on, it is never updated.

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be solution :
psexec.exe -u [user] -p [password] gpupdate.exe /force

if profile doesn't exists it will be created.